# dnn 7 authentication with service framework

Tags: android, web-services, dotnetnuke

I want to develop a external application (in android) to use some services made in dnn 7 service framework, but I want only valid users to use them so I want to first of all authenticate them. I am a noob in authentication with dnn and I couldn't find anything that a can understand. How I can achieve this, is there any example that I can follow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just add `[DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles="Administrators")]` just before the method you want to protect. I ran into the same problem and if you want to learn a bit on how to build your own webservice using the DotNetNuke framework, you can read [this blog post I made that is kind of a walkthrough to getting to know the DNN 7 Services Framework](http://concepteurweb.ca/en-ca/blog/entryid/48/creating-a-webservice-in-dotnetnuke-7).

Comment: do you have any working example or article to register and authenticate a user via services?

Comment: I do not, but I have found this: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/programatically-registering-user-dnn7